# Enable a ASP hidden label in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visibility

I Have a asp label

`<asp:Label ID="lblstarUKRollNo" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="*" CssClass="star"></asp:Label>`

and i want to enable it onchange of another textbox which calls a JS, in my javascript i tried

```
var idlblstarUKRollNo = '<%= lblstarUKRollNo.ClientID %>';
var lblstarUKRollNo = document.getElementById(idlblstarUKRollNo);
```

and to enable

`reqdddlUKJurisdiction.enabled = true;` and `lblstarUKRollNo.style.display="block";`

Both did not work for me. Can anyone help me How to solve this issue.

Comment: Just look what visible actually does http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Guidance from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773/change-visibility-of-asp-net-label-with-javascript)

After adapting to your case:

```
<asp:Label id="lblstarUKRollNo" style="display: block;" runat="server" Text="*" CssClass="star"/>
```

Then, you could make it invisible on the client side on Javascript with:

```
document.getElementById('lblstarUKRollNo').style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 4):

If you set `Visible` property to false on a server-control it wont be rendered on the client side at all. So javascript wont be able to find it. Remove `Visible` property; just use css style "`display:none`"; later use javascript to change it as "display:block"

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery - $('.someElement').attr('disabled', '');

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @mshsyayem above has said you have to set the display to none.
and you can do it in the code-behind by using the attributes. See below.

```
lblstarUKRollNo.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
```